# Android LinearLayout Line Breaks in XML

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xml-layout

I have an activity designed to get customer information.  First line gets name, 2nd line street address, third line is city, state and zip.  I can achieve what I want using a RelativeLayout and by using android:layout_below and android:layout_toRightOf, but then i have to specifically indicate a width for my views.  That width may look odd as the user reorients or switches between older and newer versions of android where everything is sized differently.  I want to utilize the weight feature of a LinearLayout, but everything just comes up all on one line.  How do I insert a line break to create rows of views within a LinearLayout?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView
android:id="@+id/custLabel"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight=".25"
android:layout_width="0dip"  
android:text="Name"/>
<EditText
android:id="@+id/customer"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight=".75"
android:layout_width="0dip"/>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/addressLabel"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight=".25"
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:text="Address"/>
<EditText
android:id="@+id/address"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight=".75"
android:layout_width="0dip"/>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/cityLabel"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight=".1"
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:text="City"/>
<EditText
android:id="@+id/city"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight=".25"
android:layout_width="0dip"/>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/stateLabel"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight=".1"
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:text="State"/>
<EditText
android:id="@+id/state"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight=".20"
android:layout_width="0dip"/>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/zipLabel"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight=".1"
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:text="Zip"/>
<EditText
android:id="@+id/zip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight=".25"
android:layout_width="0dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use nested `LinearLayout`'s to do this. I think something like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/custLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:text="Name" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/customer"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".75" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/addressLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:text="Address" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".75" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cityLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:text="City" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/city"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stateLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:text="State" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/state"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".20" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/zipLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:text="Zip" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/zip"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".20" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

should work.

Comment: That works.  Can't believe there's not a simpler way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The property of a Linear view is, it will arrange the child views in Horizontal or Vertical manner. You cannot order each TextView and Edit text in a alternate lines. For that you have to use extra layouts like table layout or even another linear layout inside the current Linear layout.

Following is the example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".25" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/custLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:text="Name" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/customer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".75" >

            <requestFocus />

        </EditText>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/addressLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:text="Address" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".75" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cityLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:text="City" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/city"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stateLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:text="State" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/state"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".20" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/zipLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:text="Zip" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/zip"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is not possible with a single LinearLayout. You should check out [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html).

Comment: I've used TableLayouts for other things.  Is it possible to set the column widths as percentages?

Comment: It is possible with the "layout-weight" attribute to set the columns to take a set amount of space, nearly identical to percentage.